# Wrapping JS into GWT cell table

Tags: javascript, jquery, gwt

In GWT Cell Table I am wrapping jquery functionality (like grouping) Using JSNI. But its throwing JavaScriptObject Exception(function is undefine).I am calling this JSNI method once after the data is loaded

```
table.setRowData(loadContactInfo());  //To Load Data
    loadGridData();    //Calling JSNI For Grouping 

     private List<ContactInfor> loadContactInfo() {
            // To load data
    List<ContactInfor> lstContact = new ArrayList<ContactInfor>();

    lstContact.add(new ContactInfor("XXX", "YYY", "t", "26", "0300",Big Street"));
            return ContactInfor;
    }

    public static native void loadGridData()/*-{
       //calling js for grouping functionality which contains table tr element
     }-*/;
```

Since its taking some few millisecond to redraw the cell table before that itself the JSNI method is called which throws JSO exception.Is there any other to wrap the JS into Cell table after the data gets loaded and Rendered? Any Suggestion on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your reply, I Used "flush()" statement after loading data see the code below

```
    table.setRowData(loadContactInfo());  
    **table.flush();    //flush force to render immediately**
    loadGridData();    

     private List<ContactInfor> loadContactInfo() {
            // To load data
    List<ContactInfor> lstContact = new ArrayList<ContactInfor>();

    lstContact.add(new ContactInfor("XXX", "YYY", "t", "26", "0300",Big Street"));
            return ContactInfor;
    }

    public static native void loadGridData()/*-{
       //calling js for grouping functionality which contains table tr element
     }-*/;
```

and also can use Scheduler.get().scheduleDeferred() for adding delay.

Answer (score 0):

There is only little information in the code above, but if your issue is because of the timing between the repaint and the jquery stuff, you may want need to use a `Scheduler.get().scheduleDeferred()` command to let the browser do it's work before you change the dom again.

http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/core/client/Scheduler.html